Do I need a transit visa for Frankfurt, Germany for an overnight stay?
I am a Canadian permanent resident and will be travelling from Delhi (DEL) to Toronto (YYZ). I will have an overnight stay at Frankfurt, Germany. Do I need transit visa? I am an Indian passport holder with valid Canadian PR.

This doesn't mention if I can stay overnight at FRA airport gemany without VISA. It say some of the airport do not operates 24 hours so will have to leave International area but not sure if FRA operates 24 hours or not. Some say it do operates 24 hours and some says it operates from 5AM - 11 PM

@phoog: It partly addresses the question in that it explains that OP would need a Schengen visa (and not just a transit visa) in order to leave the international airside area,  But the remaining question is whether one can stay overnight at FRA without leaving that area (e.g. is there a transit hotel?)

You could stay in the airside hotel. Not posting as an answer as it was very easy to find via a quick internet search, so I’m not sure if it’s what the OP is really asking about. See also https://www.sleepinginairports.net/sleep-guide/sleeping-in-frankfurt-airport.htm and https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/services/hotels/napcabs-terminal1.html

Please don't write visa in all caps.  It is not a trademark or an acronym; it is just a word.

You write

This doesn't mention if I can stay overnight at FRA airport Germany without a visa

There is a list at https://canada.diplo.de/ca-en/consular-services/visa/-/2169884

Please note that an airport transit visa only allows you a stay in the international transit area.
Airports with International Transit Area in Germany and Austria are:

Frankfurt International Airport (FRA)
München/ Munich International Airport (MUC)
Berlin Airport (BER, 6am to 11pm only)
Hamburg Airport (HAM, 4:30am to 11:30pm only)
Düsseldorf Airport (DUS, 6am to 9pm only). Only if the carrier has arranged for transit facilities with the Federal Police beforehand. Please check with your airline!


Note that three of the five airports close at night.  You can infer that the other two do not.  Frankfurt is one of the two that does not.

Are you suggesting that Frankfurt airport is open ? Post midnight?

Frankfurt airport operational hours on the website https://www.fraport.com/en/business-areas/operations/airside-and-terminal-operations/hours-of-operation.html#:~:text=Frankfurt%20Airport%20opens%20at%205,a%20ban%20on%20night%20flights.

The original poster is a person, not an aeroplane, so the operational hours of the airfield doesn't affect them.

@SaranshSharma I am not suggesting that it is open past midnight.  I am stating that it never closes.  As Tom Jin notes, the page you link to concerns hours during which airplanes may take off and land.  The hours during which German airport terminals close to transit passengers are given on the page linked in this answer, and there are no such hours for Frankfurt or Munich, because the terminals are always open.

As an Indian citizen you need a transit visa for Germany and the Frankfurt airport operates from 5 AM to 11 PM check Frankfurt airport website.
See this note source here Germany Transit Visa Conditions 
The document first states
The vast majority of foreign travelers benefit from the “transit privilege” - if during a stopover at a
German airport, you do not leave the International Airport Area and if the destination is not in a Schengen country, you do not need a transit visa.
… conditions and then it says
Nationals of the following countries do not have the transit privilege and therefore require an airport transit visa (category A) for transit at a German airport
Unfortunately India is one of them.
Then the document outlines the exhaustive list of exception too but as I see you have a PR in Canada and the exception does not state Canada either
Then this another source that I found says Canada 2
Finally the German Embassy in Canada website3states you don’t need a transit visa if you are a permanent resident.
So there you go with Indian citizen and Canadian PR you don’t need a transit visa but  you will have to   stay in the International area.

The document is faulty because it is targeted at residents of the United States.  The list of exceptions is not exhaustive.  A Canadian residence permit does exempt a traveler from the airport transit visa requirement.  It's better to look at the site of the German missions in Canada when answering a question from someone who is in Canada.

@phoog what’s a faulty document ?

It is but it’s a reference point I am not claiming that it’s should be used for someone in Canada , as I mentioned down the line and referenced German embassy in Canada

A faulty document is one with incorrect or, as in this case, incomplete information.  Mentioning it in this answer is confusing, especially since you mention it first and say "I see you have a PR in Canada and the exception does not state Canada either."  It is misleading.
